# How to use webcam to capture each frame displayed with OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opencv, opengl, webcam

My goal is to use camera to take pictures of each frame updated on my monitor. Code is written in C++/OpenGL/OpenCV. OpenGL is used to draw screen, OpenCV is used to control webcam.

```
    void display()
    {
        draw();

        glutSwapBuffers();

        Sleep(5000);

        takeOnePicture();  // using OpenCV VideoCapture >> operator

        Sleep(5000);
    }
```

My questions are:

- When exactly is glutSwapBuffers() executed?  or when exactly is content put on screen?
- Is there a callback function in OpenGL that tells me when screen has been fully updated?
- Does it make sense if I debug this code step by step?  I did, screen updates after takeOnePicture()...

Let me know anyways that I can achieve my goal:
Take pictures of each frame drawn on the screen...

Comment: I also tried putting Sleep(5000); takeOnePicture(); Sleep(5000); in the idle() function, still, the timestamp when picture is taken doesn't match what I expected. e.g. second picture captures the first frame on screen...

Comment: Okay, seems like I have to initialize VideoCapture everytime takeOnePicture() function is called in idle()...

Comment: ^^ oh, please *don't* initialize the capture once per frame(that'll be slow as molasses). do that *once*, and just read an image whenever you need it.

Comment: @berak That won't work because the frame read out won't be the latest one... it's probably an old frame in the buffer...